# undefined (extra) object in knockoutjs observableArray created from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am struggling to convert a JSON string to an observable array for use in a foreach loop in HTML. I am getting an extra undefined property in the observable array when I loop through it. Any help will be greatly apreciated. Here's my code:

```
var regions = '{"1":{"id":1,"name":"Scotland"},"3":{"id":3,"name":"North West"},"7":{"id":7,"name":"South East"},"5":{"id":5,"name":"East Anglia"},"9":{"id":9,"name":"Wales"},"8":{"id":8,"name":"South West"},"6":{"id":6,"name":"Greater London"},"2":{"id":2,"name":"North East"},"4":{"id":4,"name":"Midlands"}}';

this.regions = ko.observableArray();
ko.mapping.fromJSON(regions, {}, this.regions());

ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.regions(), function(region){
               console.log(region);
            });
```

When I run my forloop - I get 10 console logs when there are only 9 objects in the JSON string, the first log is undefined and the next 9 are correct.

```
undefined
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
store-locator.html:174 Object {id: function, name: function}
```

I am able to loop through the array in html with the following code, but again I get an empty list item at the begining of my list followed by 9 regions names.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root.regions()">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

P.S I'm pretty sure the JSON is valid, it's a php array that has been converted using json_encode()

Comment: You `regoins` does not contain an **array** but an object which has proeprties called 1,2,3,4 etc. this is not supported by the mapping plugin so it cannot properly create an array for you. If you change your `regions` to contain a real array then it is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gpm2zuvs/

Comment: If you cannot alter what you get from the server side, I suggest you use ko.utils.parseJson instead to do this task. Check the console output of the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f1dbLq3j/11/. Check the console output of the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is a lot easier to do in Angular. Thanks for your comments, both useful answers but memesv' answer was what I really needed to know.

Changed the backend in the end to provide an array without keys so knockout was then able to interpret they data correctly.

Many thanks.
Ash